# i inserting data in to a table but raises the error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is the code

```
def parse_listings(self, response): 
 
        '''
        content = ''
        with open('incidec1.html', 'r' ) as f:
             for line in f.read():
                 content += line
        response = Selector(text=content)
        brand = response.css('div[class="fs21"]').css('span').css('a::text').get()
        title = response.css('div[class="klavikab lilac"]').css('span::text').get()
      
        t = (id, brand,title)
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO products VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(id, brand, title)) 
        
        mydb.commit()
        print('complete.')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
     incidecoderspider.parse_listings(incidecoderspider,'')'
```

this the output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "incidecoder1.py", line 98, in <module>
        incidecoderspider.parse_listings(incidecoderspider,'')
      File "incidecoder1.py", line 80, in parse_listings
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO products VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(id, brand, title, photo, ingredients)) 
   
     
    AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

i tried very much but can't understanfd what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a value that you didn't define: `id`.  Normally, this would get you an "undefined symbol" error.  However, `id` *is* defined: it's a built-in function.

Simply change the variable name so that you don't collide with a built-in item (such as product_id), and then give that variable a value.

Comment: Thank you i changed the variable name id to product_id and it starts working.